# How can I make this movement relative to my camera direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, vectormath

I need to move my target object in world space relative to the direction the main camera is facing but only on the x&z axis and relative to the my player on the on the y axis.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour {

public string raise = "Raise";
public string lower = "Lower";
public string left = "Left";
public string right = "Right";
public string closer = "Closer";
public string further = "Further";

public GameObject target;


private float xPos;
private float yPos;
private float zPos;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {


    xPos = target.transform.position.x;
    yPos = target.transform.position.y;
    zPos = target.transform.position.z;

}

void FixedUpdate () {

    Vector3 currPos = target.transform.position;
    Vector3 nextPos = new Vector3 (xPos, yPos, zPos);

    target.GetComponent < Rigidbody > ().velocity = (nextPos - currPos) * 10;

    if (Input.GetButton (raise)) {
        print ("Moving Up");
        yPos = yPos + 0.05f;
    }
    if (Input.GetButton (lower)) {
        print ("Moving Down");
        yPos = yPos - 0.05f;
    }
    if (Input.GetButton (left)) {
        print ("Moving Left");
        xPos = xPos - 0.05f;
    }
    if (Input.GetButton (right)) {
        print ("Moving Right");
        xPos = xPos + 0.05f;
    }
    if (Input.GetButton (closer)) {
        print ("Moving Closer");
        zPos = zPos - 0.05f;
    }
    if (Input.GetButton (further)) {
        print ("Moving Further");
        zPos = zPos + 0.05f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the camera's direction like this:

```
var camDir = Camera.main.transform.forward;
```

You only want the x/y component, so we're going to renormalise that vector:

```
camDir.y = 0;
camDir.Normalized();
```

That's the forward vector. Because it's effectively a 2D vector now, we can get the cam's right-hand vector easily:

```
var camRight = new Vector3(camDir.z, 0f, -camDir.x);
```

I'm going to assum your player's up direction is just up the y axis. If it's different, sub in that vector:

```
var playerUp = Vector3.up;
```

Now, in your sample you're doing manual integration, then passing it off to the rigid body system to do integration again. Let's just work out our own velocity directly:

```
var newVel = Vector3.zero;
if (/*left*/) newVel -= camRight * 0.05;
if (/*right*/) newVel += camRight * 0.05;
if (/*closer*/) newVel -= camDir * 0.05;
if (/*farter*/) newVel += camDir * 0.05;
if (/*raise*/) newVel += playerUp * 0.05;
if (/*lower*/) newVel -= playerUp * 0.05;
```

Change that 0.05 if you want to move faster or more slowly. You can do lots of stuff here to make controls feel really nice, like having a little deadzone or feeding directly off analogue input rather than buttons.

Then finally commit that into the rigid body:

```
target.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = newVel;
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer tenpn, that really helps me out.
but now when I release the raise button the height resets. So do I go currentPos - newVel?

Comment: I need more details. You start on the floor, hit raise, and what happens? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Okay I see, it's for a telekinesis system so when I press the raise object button it should set the height of the object off the ground and stay in that spot when I release the button.

Comment: then rigid bodies are the wrong answer here. do a similar thing, but replace the `.velocity = call` with `target.transform.position += newVel * Time.deltaTime`. Remove the rigidbody from from the object if it doesn't need to move with physics, or set it to kinetic.

Comment: I'm confused now, why cant I use rigidBodies? Is there a way to get my existing code relative to the camera? That levitated when I let go of the button like I need.